# Mongoose set empty array when update model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with mongoose. I use MEAN stack.

I have an House Schema with some fields. When I update the house (with save method) mongoose update all fields but set an array in nested object empty. Why?

**HOUSE SCHEMA**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const posSchema = require('./pos');
const reviewSchema = require('./reviews');
const roomSchema = require('./rooms');
const contactSchema = require('./contacts');
const nearSchema = require('./nears');

const houseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: { type: String, required: true },

    description: { type: String, required: true },

    shared: {
       description: { type: String, required: true },
       photos: { type: [String], required: true }
     },

    // OTHER FIELDS

}, { timestamps: true });

mongoose.model('House', houseSchema);
```

**UPDATE FUNCTION**

```
House.findById(body.house._id, "-__v", async (err, house) => {

    if (err) { return res.status(400).json(err); }
    else if (!house) { return res.status(400); }

    house.title = body.house.title;
    house.totalSize = parseInt(body.house.totalSize.toString());
    house.bathrooms = parseInt(body.house.bathrooms.toString());
    house.totalBeds = parseInt(body.house.totalBeds.toString());
    house.description = body.house.description;
    house.totalFreeBeds = parseInt(body.house.totalFreeBeds.toString());
    house.minPrice = parseFloat(body.house.minPrice.toString()).toFixed(2);
    house.type = body.house.type;
    house.level = body.house.level;
    house.top_floor = body.house.top_floor;

    house.rooms = body.house.rooms;

    house.checkboxes = body.house.checkboxes;
    house.contacts = body.house.contacts;
    house.pos = body.house.pos;

    house.save(err => {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return res.status(400).json(err); }
        return res.status(200).json({ status: 200, remove: remove });
    });
        
});
```

Before updating house.shared.photos is ["foo", "bar"]

After is [].

***Why?***

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the  `house.shared` anywhere.

Try adding `house.shared = body.house.shared` before `save` call.

Comment: I had already tried it. It doesn't work anyway. Mongoose set array empty